# Multiple Aggregations Across Partition Keys Only Work From Web Base Azure Data Explorer But Not From Python Client Library

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm working with the Azure Core API. Using the web based data explorer, I'm able to successfully run a query that has multiple aggregations across multiple partitions. Yet when I attempt to run such a query from my shell using the Azure client library for Python (`pip install azure-cosmos==4.0.0`), I get an error message. I've tried two variations of the query, where one included the partition key and one didn't. Both queries returned the same error message.

```
container = database.get_container_client('some_container')
query1 = "select c.fmonth, c.fquarter, c.fyear, sum(c.revenue) as actual_revenue__sum, sum(c.predicted_revenue_m1) as predicted_revenue__sum from c where c.fyear=2020 group by c.fmonth, c.fquarter, c.fyear"
query2 = "select c.fmonth, c.fquarter, c.fyear, sum(c.revenue) as actual_revenue__sum, sum(c.predicted_revenue_m1) as predicted_revenue__sum from c where c.date_start >='2020-01-01' and c.date_start < '2021-01-01' group by c.fmonth, c.fquarter, c.fyear"
res = container.query_items(query1, enable_cross_partition_query=True)
```

Error Message Returned:
CosmosHttpResponseError: (BadRequest) Message: {"Errors":["Cross partition query only supports 'VALUE ' for aggregates."]}
ActivityId: 4961b99e-7032-4eac-ae84-2c8cab03a496, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0

Answer (score 0):

> Errors out for aggregates on multiple partitions, with enable cross
>   partition query set to true, but no "value" keyword present

If you want to use aggregates on multiple partitions,`select value count(1) from c`,this will work.

But python sdk doesn't support `group by` now.
Refer to this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-cosmos-db-supports-group-by-for-queries-for-sql-core-api/),.net sdk and js sdk support `group by`.Other sdk will support later.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Any idea on when the Python SDK will support the group by?

Comment: This is in their plan.I think it will come soon.Please pay attention to python sdk release.